# Pointer in C giving negative values

Tags: c, pointers

What I'm trying to do is when the value of harePosition is less than 1 than I want it to just equal 1. But when I print the value it's giving me negative values.

I'm not very experienced with pointers and I'm positive it's my lack of understanding that's causing my issues.

```
int main()
{
int *harePosition = 1, *tortoisePosition = 1;

bool running = 1;

char *sameSpot = "OUCH!!!";

printRace();

srand(time(NULL)); //Allows rand() to create random numbers

while(running){

    harePosition = moveHare(harePosition); //calls the function to determine what action will be taken

    printf("Hare Position is: %d\n", harePosition); //prints to the screen, I'm using this to troubleshoot if the issue was resolved. 

    tortoisePosition = tortoiseMove(tortoisePosition);

int *moveHare(unsigned int *harePosition) // function where the issue is happening
{

int hareAction;

hareAction = rand () % 10; // randomly picks a number

if(hareAction < 2){ // based on the hareAction chooses one of the if statements and preforms a math operation 
    harePosition = harePosition;
}
else if(hareAction > 1 && hareAction < 4){
    harePosition += 9;
}
else if(hareAction == 4){
    harePosition -= 12;
}
else if(hareAction > 4 && hareAction< 8){
    harePosition += 1;
}
else{
    harePosition -= 2;
}

if(harePosition < 1){ // Suppose to prevent the harePosition from being less than one
   return = 1;
}

return harePosition;

}
```

Comment: There is no question in your question.

Comment: Pointers can't be negative, it's just displaying as such because you wrongly print it as if it was a signed integer. Don't print pointers using `%d` - that's potentially the wrong size and definitely the wrong signedness. Use `%p` to print pointers.

Comment: The code in the question will not compile for multiple reasons, yet the question seems to be asking about a running program (since it asks about something that is printed by the program). So the code in the question is not the code actually used in the problem being asked about. You must provide a [mcve] with the **exact code** that shows the problem.

Comment: `int *harePosition = 1;` is an error. if you do not see an error message then please configure your compiler to show errors

Comment: among other issues, there's no use for this line: `harePosition = harePosition;`

Comment: @M.M, I'm not sure `int *x = 1;` is an *error* as defined by the standard. It's certainly not a good idea but neither is UB and the standard allows that without forced error as well.

Comment: @paxdiablo it's a constraint violation requiring a diagnostic  (personally I use the term "error" for all constraint violations, since the compiler is entitled to reject the program on that basis)

Comment: @M.M: I stand corrected. The constraints for simple assignment do indeed state that you should only assign a compatible pointer type or null pointer. Apologies and updated my answer to suit.

Comment: `return = 1;` is invalid syntax.  But the real problem here is that you're trying to compare a pointer to integer constants.  It would make more sense to dereference it, i.e. `*harePosition`, to get an actual integer that you can meaningfully compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *harePosition = 1;
```

will create a *pointer* and make it point to the memory location 1<sup>(a)</sup>. This is not what you need.

In fact, there is absolutely no need to use pointers in your code since you pass in the value and return the new value<sup>(b)</sup>. So, in simpler form, what you would need would be:

```
int fn (int someVal) {
    return someVal + 42;
}

int val = 7;
val = fn (val); // now it will be 49.
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> At least in systems that allow it. I think this statement should have at least generated a diagnostic message of some sort since, as `ISO C11 Simple assignment` points out in its constraints, you should only assign a compatible pointer or a null pointer, *not* some arbitrary integer.

---

<sup>(b)</sup> Generally, the only reason to pass in a pointer is to emulate pass-by-reference in a language that doesn't have it. I sincerely hope at some point that ISO just bites the bullet and adds *real* pass-by-reference to the language. Then about 80% of C problems will disappear :-)

If you *did* need to pass it in by (emulated-)reference, you have to make sure you distinguish between the *pointer* and the *value* it points to. For example:

```
void fn (int *pSomeVal) {   // Receive a POINTER to an int.
    *pSomeVal += 42;        // Update the thing it points TO.
}

int val = 7;
fn (&val);                  // Pass POINTER to the int,
                            //   then val becomes 49.
```

Comment: The other 80% of C problems are related to buffer overflows.

Comment: The only problem pass-by-reference solves is with defining operator overloads, which C doesn't support, and special member functions, which C also doesn't support.

Comment: @Ben, pass-by-reference will solve the problem of people mis-understanding what they can do to variables inside a function and have it echo back to the caller, and also of people stuffing up what's a pointer and what's a value. As evidenced by this question :-) Obviously, seasoned C-bods like us have nutted it out but there are still a lot of people coming through the educational system (though whether they're learning C is another matter).

Comment: @paxdiablo: Having an <strike>easier</strike> less visible way of aliasing is not a substitute for understanding aliasing.  Visibility of aliasing is a good thing.  Multiple return values would be far more useful to beginners than pass-by-reference.

Comment: @Ben, well, we have that as well, in the ability to return structs. But I'll admit Python's way of automatically unpacking a return "set" into multiple variables is very nice. Maybe I should hope for that as well :-)

Comment: Using the verbiage of your answer, returning a struct is an effective way to emulate multiple return values in a language that doesn't have them.  But yeah, ad-hoc tuples ala C# are very nice (to give a statically-typed example unlike Python or MATLAB).